# Closure of a set: Point Set Topology

Tags: general-topology

I am given a set B $=\big\{\big(1-\frac{1}{n}\big)\times \frac{1}{2}:n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\big\}$.

My thoughts: Now when looking at this set I see that 1 is never obtained how ever the points in B are getting very close to it, which leads me to believe that the closure of this set denote $B_{\ closure}= B \cup \{1 \times \frac{1}{2} \}$.

Problem: Determine the closure of the following subset of the ordered square.

Comment: use for closure: $\overline{B}$ to avoid confusion. $B'$ usually stand for the set of accumulation points

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Can you find another $a<1$ such that $1\times a$ is an upper bound for $B$? What is the least such $a?$ (Upshot: $B$ *does* have a single limit point, but you have not correctly determined it.)

Comment: Is this set B including the ordered pairs that fall in their respective boxes? For instance does $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$ contain all ordered pairs of the form $(a,b)$ where $a,b\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: No. $\frac12\times\frac12$ is alternative notation for the ordered pair $\left(\frac12,\frac12\right).$ The set $B$ is comprised of the ordered pairs $$0\times\frac12,\frac12\times\frac12,\frac23\times\frac12,\frac34\times\frac12,...,\frac{n-1}{n}\times\frac12,....$$ Does that clear things up for you a bit?

Comment: Okay, yes that does clear some things up. I will think a bit more about it.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you get stuck, and I'll see if I can help you out further.

Comment: Oh, my goodness! I just realized I made an error in my answer. It is now fixed. My sincerest apologies.